# Convex function of independent vs. correlated random variables

Tags: probability

Let $f\colon\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be convex and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables. Is it true that $\mathbb E f(n\cdot X_1) \ge \mathbb E f(X_1 + \cdots + X_n)$?

It seems like one approach is to show that $X$ is a mean-preserving spread of the average of $n$ independent copies of $X$. Is there a name for this sort of result? (Also, is there a name for this sort of inequality?)

Comment: I believe the opposite direction is true: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Comment: What you are asking is probably not true in general. Think about a simple case $X_1, X_2$ are i.i.d. uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. So $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=0, \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]>0$ for $i=1,2$. Take $f(x)=x^2$. Then $\mathbb{E}f(2X_1)=4\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)$, while the right-hand side $\mathbb{E}((X_1+X_2)^2)=2\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)$, which is strictly less than the left-hand side.

Comment: My bad—I had the inequality going the wrong way originally (fixed now). In the fixed version, when $X_i$ are standard Gaussian, we have that the mean is a Gaussian with lower variance, so $X_1$ is a mean-preserving spread of the mean. By Jensen, the desired inequality holds.

Comment: If the solution of a problem is known to you, you should state that in the body of the Question and explain why the solution in the related Question (also by you) requires or deserves an alternative.  Otherwise you will seem to be asking Readers to rehearse material already well-known to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the  [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) for finite form with $a_i = 1$ and $x_i = nX_i$

$$f\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) = f\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(nX_i)}{n}\right) \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nf(nX_i)}{n}  $$

Then
$$\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) \right] \le \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nf(nX_i)}{n} \right] =\mathbb{E}[f(nX_1)]$$

PS: I don't think there is a specific name for this inequality