# Convex function of independent vs. correlated random variables redux

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $f\colon\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be convex and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables (e.g., uniform). Furthermore, suppose $g_1,\ldots,g_n\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are increasing. Is it true that $$\mathbb E f(g_1(X_1) + g_2(X_1) + \cdots + g_n(X_1)) \ge \mathbb E f(g_1(X_1) + g_2(X_2) + \cdots + g_n(X_n))? $$

Like the previous version of this question ([Convex function of independent vs. correlated random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4055360/351108)), which is the special case where the $g_i$ are all the identity, it seems like one approach is to show that $g_1(X_1) + \cdots + g_n(X_1)$ is a mean-preserving spread of $g_1(X_1) + \cdots + g_n(X_n)$. As before, I am also curious if there is a name for this sort of result/inequality.

Comment: Both sides of the inequality that you have proposed, seem equal to me.

Comment: Note that the arguments to the $g_i$ on the left-hand side are all $X_1$ (as opposed to $X_i$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proof using second-order stochastic dominance:

The inequality follows if we show that $\sum_i g_i(X_1)\succeq \sum_i g_i(X_i)$ in the sense of second-order stochastic dominance (see, e.g., https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165489687900618). Clearly, $\mathbb E \sum_i g_i(X_1) = \mathbb E \sum_i g_i(X_i)$.
So it remains to check that that the integrated quantile functions satisfy the second-order stochastic dominance property.

For a random variable $X$, let $Q_X$ denote its quantile function. Let $Y = \sum_i g_i(X_1)$ and $Z = \sum_i g_i(X_i)$. Then, since each $g_i$ is increasing,
$$ \int_\tau^1 Q_Y(t) \,dt = \sum_i \int_\tau^1 Q_{g_i(X_1)}(t)\,dt.$$
We have that $\int_\tau^1 Q_X(t) = \sup_{R\in\mathcal{R}_\tau} \mathbb E(RX)$, where $\mathcal{R}_\tau$ is the set of non-negative random variables (defined on the same probability space as $X$) that take values between $0$ and $1$ and have mean at most $\tau$. This lets us deduce the claimed stochastic dominance:
\begin{align*}
 \int_\tau^1 Q_Y(t) &= \sum_i \int_\tau^1 Q_{g_i(X_1)}(t)\,dt \\
  &= \sum_i \sup_{R\in\mathcal{R}_\tau} \mathbb E(R\cdot g_i(X_1)) \\
  &= \sum_i \sup_{R\in\mathcal{R}_\tau} \mathbb E(R\cdot g_i(X_i))
\\ &\ge \sup_{R\in\mathcal{R}_\tau}\mathbb E\Big(R\sum_i g_i(X_i)\Big) \\
&= \int_\tau^1 Q_Z(t)\,dt.
\end{align*}